# Laravel 5 QueryException When I try to call Edit Function

Tags: laravel-routing

I am learning about Laravel 5 and studying from this source
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13

But when I try to make my own project which involves editing like the source taught me, I got "QueryException in Connection.php line 620:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mscustomer.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `mscustomer` where `mscustomer`.`id` = 1 limit 1)"

Here are the code snippets

Routes.php

```
Route::get('edit/{member}', 'MemberController@edit');
```

MemberController.php

```
    public function edit($custid)
{$member=mscustomer::findOrFail($custid);return view('member.edit' ,compact('member'));}
```

And here is the edit.blade.php

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<hr/>

{!!Form::open(['url'=>'member'])!!}
<div class="form-group">

{!!Form::label('custname','Name :')!!}
{!!Form::text('custname',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('password','Password :')!!}
{!!Form::password('password',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('email','E-mail :')!!}
{!!Form::text('email',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

```
{!!Form::submit('Register')!!}

{!!Form::close()!!}

@if ($errors->any())
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<br>{{ $error }}</br>

@endforeach

@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, the id column doesnt' exist in Database.

If you did setup your database migrations properly you wanna run "php artisan migrate". IF you didn't. You need to set them up befor you can start using your Eloquent models.

Comment: I do have a column named "custid", and in my MemberController I also use $custid as the parameter, what I can't understand is why is the query looking for mscustomer.id? where did the .id came from?

Comment: The ->findOrFail method from your model automatically looks for id field. Possible solutions, rename your "custid" to just "id" or use a where instead of a simple find.

I would rename your column, keeping the standard name for colums like this automates a lot of work.

Good luck

Comment: Wow it works! thanks a lot Borjante! I did not know that findorfail automatically look for id, and it works after I changed my column name!
Sorry because I don't have enough reputation to vote you yet